# adding current position of a loop with previous position

Tags: python

This might be a silly question but
I have a loop where n is a user input

```
n = input("enter number"):
for i in range(n):
    a = input("enter a value for each n")
```

now i need to add the current position of a with the previous position of a

```
    c = a[n] + a[n-1]
```

how do i do that?

lets say n = 5 and a = 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: `a[n] += a[n-1]`? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: ya. i do not want to do it that way. Is there a solution using enumerate or iterate??

Comment: *"i do not want to do it that way"* - why not, what are your criteria? *"Is there a solution using enumerate or iterate??"* - have you tried that? What happened? This is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service, put some effort in yourself.

Comment: It's not clear what you want your code to do. Also, there's a syntax error on the 1st line. If you're not using Python 2 your code has further errors, and if you _are_ using Python 2 then you shouldn't be using `input()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if you want your script to add numbers, you need to store the sum in a variable

n = int(input("enter number"))
b = 0 # store sum here
for i in range(n):
    a = int(input("enter a value for each n"))
    b = b + a
    print(b)

enter number4
enter a value for each n2
2
enter a value for each n3
5
enter a value for each n4
9
enter a value for each n6
15
```